# Property 'CLUSTER_CLICK' does not exist (Angular)

Tags: angular

This project contains the native google maps plugin, georeferencing and functionality for cluster markers.

I am currently trying to clone this repository:

```
https://github.com/ghadeer-io/ionic-3-google-maps-example
```

(link of tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qBYlf2qKGc&t=1s)

once cloned, I do `npm install`

later, `ionic cordova platform add android`

later `ionic serve` and this is the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The project is 8 months old. You should write about this bug on the issues page of the repository. In the meanwhile, try to modify the shown code:

`markerCluster.on(GoogleMapsEvent.CLUSTER_CLICK).subscribe ...`

to this:

`markerCluster.on(GoogleMapsEvent["CLUSTER_CLICK"]).subscribe ...`